# How do I appropriately code a gamm() model with an inverse.gaussian family and autocorrelation structure?

Tags: autocorrelation, biostatistics, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, inverse-gaussian-distribution

I am incredibly new to generalized additive modeling, so I apologize in advance for any and all naiveté. But I believe GAMMs are the appropriate methodology for my data. I am working with fish movement data from a telemetry study in a river. I have 72 individual fish (FishIDs) and data points (detections) are not equally spaced in time (unequal tracking intervals). My response variable is movement rate, and I have different environmental covariates I'd like to explore including day of year (DOY) in order to look at seasonal patterns in movement. I also think that including DOY is going to help me account for temporal autocorrelation. Day of year is actually day of study, since my study spans 2 years.

I have determined (hopefully correctly) that my data is best fit with an inverse.gaussian distribution and a log link function due to the fact that I have far more low movement rates than high movement rates (range from 1.001m/day - 15,615m/day with a mean of 251m/day).
(I did this by building basic `gams()` with just `s(DOY)` and `s(FishID, bs = "re")` but with different family arguments to see what was best via AIC and draw() ).
(let me know if it would be helpful to see these original steps in my code).

So with that, I am running into errors when I try to fit different correlation structures to my data to see if adding a correlation structure improves model fit (via comparing AIC). Accounting for autocorrelation is one reason I was drawn to gams in the first place, since inherently each fish's movement is dependent on the movement that proceeded it. When I do a family argument such as gaussian or Gamma, I don't have issues here. But as soon as I try to fit a `gamm()` with `inverse.gaussian(link = log)` I get errors. Here is my workflow:

```r
mm1 = gam(MoveRate ~ s(DOY) + s(FishID, bs = "re"), data = mv, 
        family = inverse.gaussian(link="log"), method = 'REML')

# testing for autocorr 
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
acf(resid(mm1), main = "ACF") # maybe a significant lag of 1?
pacf(resid(mm1), main = "pACF")
```

I then get this plot indicating (I think) that I have autocorrelation at lag = 1: [image]

So then, I change my model to a gamm() structure in order to compare a model with autocorrelation structure to a model without to see if accounting for autocorrelation improves model fit.

```r
# model without corr
mm1 = gamm(MoveRate ~ s(DOY), data = mv, family = Gamma(link = "log"), 
       random = list(FishID= ~ 1), method = 'REML', niterPQL = 500) 
    # am I coding Random effect right?

# corSpher structure, recommended because unequally spaced data in time? 
mm1b = gamm(MoveRate ~ s(DOY), data = mv, 
       family = Gamma(link = "log"), random = list(FishID= ~ 1), 
       correlation = corSpher(form = ~ DOY|FishID, nugget = TRUE), 
       method = 'REML',
            niterPQL = 100
            ) # get an ERROR here

# corARMA structure  
# lag = 1 
mm1c = gamm(MoveRate ~ s(DOY) ,data = mv, 
       family = inverse.gaussian(link="log"), 
       random = list(FishID= ~ 1), 
            correlation = corARMA(form = ~1|DOY, p = 1), 
                                   method = 'REML',
            niterPQL = 500 # trying to increase iterations to help convergence?
            ) # get an ERROR here too
```

But I cannot get these models with any kind of correlation structure to successfully run so that I can then compare all 3 models. I can get the correlation models to run with a different family, but I think that is against the point if I found that inverse.gaussian was the best when compared to others (e.g., gamma, gaussian, tw) in my original gam() building.

So with all that, does anyone know why my models might not be running successfully with an inverse.gaussian family and a correlation structure? Are these the appropriate correlation structures to even be testing, especially since my data isn't equally spaced temporally? And is anything else glaringly wrong with my methodology so far?

My basic thoughts are to determine whether my models should incorporate a correlation structure or not and then move on from there to test other covariates in additional a priori models. So that moving forward all models I'm considering will either have a correlation structure because that was determined to fit my data best, or not have a correlation structure because I found the opposite was true.

Any guidance or help is most appreciated!! I am eager to learn as much as I can to complete this analysis appropriately and correctly.